# Can I call addFieldToFilter via di.xml? / Set a global filter on product collection

Tags: product-collection, dependency-injection, magento-2.2.5

I am working with `vendor/smile/elasticsuite/src/module-elasticsuite-catalog/Model/ResourceModel/Product/Fulltext/Collection.php` which extends the `\Magento\Catalog\Model\ResourceModel\Product\Collection`.

I need to call

```
    $this->addFieldToFilter('custom_visible', 1);
```

on each creation of the collection.

Can I do this somehow via `di.xml` ? Or what is the best way to do this?

In legacy code, `\Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\AbstractProduct::_getProductCollection` was overwritten, but this seems to fire to late.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think you can call a method via `di.xml` and I don't think you should even if you could. `di.xml` should be declarative and not imperative.
But anyway...
If your goal is to filter the product collection by a specific attribute every time you display a product collection in the frontend you can try this.

Via rewrites:
Rewrite the class in question and `_construct` method (notice the single underscore in the method name) you can call `parent::_construct()` and the `$this->addAttributeToFilter(....)`.

Or you can do the same in the method `_initSelect`. But you should double check if this is not overwritten in other child classes (for configurable or bundle products).

Via Plugin:
Pluginize (with before or around) the method `load` from the same collection class and add your filter.  Just make sure you add the filter only for frontend area so you don't screw up the admin product collections.